# How to create dispatcher or associate an object with dispatcher to BeginInvoke calls

Tags: c#, .net, events, dispatcher, begininvoke

I am new to C# and was developing an event based system to handle inputs from threads. The UI has to be updated from the response received from a thread. I found in one of the articles and used BeginInvoke on the form. However, my question is,

```
class CustomDispatcher
{
    public void Routine1()
    {}
    public BeginInvoke()
    {
        // like in control.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{ Routine1(); });
        // This should execute Routine1 asynchronously. This BeginInvoke will be called from a different thread.
    }
}
```

The BeginInvoke is functioning well when the form instance is used. However, i am not able to figure out, if i can mimic this dispatching functionality of the form to my class instance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're new to C#, I would suggest you get a bit more experience before you start creating your own eventing and threading framework. What you're asking for can be done, but you're likely to run into problems along the way which will be easier to tackle once you're familiar with C#.

Comment: I guess you could use the applications dispatcher `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you're making a new API, and want to write asynchronous methods, I'd strongly recommend designing your API around the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) classes.

This will allow it to work directly with the `async`/`await` support in C# 5.

In your case, since `Routine1` is a void method, you could write a method that handles it asynchronously, ie:

```
public Task Routine1Async()
{
    // Perform the work asynchronously...
}
```

Or, using C# 5:

```
public async Task Routine1Async()
{
    // Perform the work taking advantage of the await keyword...
    await SomeOtherMethodAsync(); // etc
}
```

That being said, if this is purely just going to call `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`, I would leave it out of your API, and let the caller turn it into an asynchronous method as needed.  I would not recommend making an asynchronous API which merely wraps the synchronous API.

Comment: @RahulW Yes, if you do it right.  See: http://reedcopsey.com/2010/03/18/parallelism-in-net-part-15-making-tasks-run-the-taskscheduler/